# Angular UI-Router fails to load template that I didn't ask for

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Plunker  Code Showing Issue Described Below](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bz3Qhf1eDuFrnKI0qnUo?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bz3Qhf1eDuFrnKI0qnUo?p=preview

I am using two components of the AngularUI suite, UI-Router and UI-Bootstrap.
UI-Router is responsible for loading templates when the user clicks on my top navbar links.

*Only the first two links under 'UI Widget Templates' (AngularUI-Bootstrap and Alert)  are active*

[image]

UI-Bootstrap is responsible for making nice widgets within the templates.
I seem to have UI-Router properly configured in that I am loading the proper templates and those templates have access to the correct controller. The problem I am having is that my UI-Bootstrap components are failing to load and generating odd errors which seem to indicate they are somehow attempting to load templates themselves??? 
What have I mishandled in my implementation that is keeping the Bootstrap-UI directives from loading?

**HTML Template for Alert dropdown link**

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
  <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active"           disabled="tab.disabled">
    {{tab.content}}
  </tab>
  <tab select="alertMe()">
  <tab-heading>
    <i class="icon-bell"></i> Select me for alert!
  </tab-heading>
  I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
  </tab>
 </tabset>

{{tabs}}
```

**Error Message from console when Alert template loads**

[image]

**Angular Goodness**

```
angular.module("uiRouterExample", [
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap']).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'BSCtrl'
        })
        .state('angularBS', {
            url: '/angularBS',
            templateUrl: 'templates/angularBS.html',
            controller: 'BSCtrl'
        })
        .state('alert', {
            url: '/alert',
            templateUrl: 'templates/alert.html',
            controller: 'BSCtrl'
        })
    ;
})
.controller('BSCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.tabs = [
      { title:"Accordion", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
      { title:"Alert", content:"Dynamic content 2"},
      {title:"Buttons", content:"More Dynamic Content"}
    ];

    $scope.test="Hello World";

    $scope.alerts = [
      { type: 'error', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' }, 
      { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
    ];

    $scope.addAlert = function() {
      $scope.alerts.push({msg: "Another alert!"});
    };

    $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
      $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UI-Bootstrap relies on the presence of templates which are not present in the ui-bootstrap-[version].js file. The build files configuration options are described [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files). A relevant snippet:

> Files with the -tpls in their name have
>   bootstrap-specific templates bundled with directives. For people who
>   want to take all the directives and don't need to customize anything
>   the solution is to grab a file named
>   ui-bootstrap-tpls-[version].min.js. If, on the other hand default
>   templates are not what you need you could take
>   ui-bootstrap-[version].min.js and provide your own templates...

In the plunkr, you are using ui-bootstrap-0.7.0.js, not ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js. The former is not bundled with the templates, but still has references to them hard-coded under the directives' templateUrls, for example:

```
.directive('alert', function() {
  return {
    ...
    templateUrl:'template/alert/alert.html',
    ...
  };
}])
```

---

Edit, including @inolasco's answer:

If you use ui-bootstrap-tpls.js and still have this issue, it might be that you need to add

```
'ui.bootstrap.tpls'
```

to your module.

Comment: Please add @inolasco answer!

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the accepted answer, which lead me to solve a similar issue. if you use **ui-bootstrap-tpls.js** and still have this issue, it might be that you need to add

> 'ui.bootstrap.tpls'

to your module. That worked for me.

Comment: hope @Sarah adds this to her answer